# Using custom business hour within resample in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying get a resample within a defined custom business hours in pandas. 
I am trying to get a sum of the invested column in a custom business day. (custom business day: 23:30-7:00)

```
Date                Name    Invested
3/16/2017 11:50 PM  John    0.3
3/17/2017 12:54 AM  John    0.25
3/17/2017 1:02 AM   John    0.25
3/17/2017 1:05 AM   John    0.025
3/17/2017 1:31 AM   John    0.083333
3/17/2017 2:00 AM   John    0.2
3/17/2017 2:07 AM   John    0.2
```

Code

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessHour
bh = BusinessHour(start='23:30', end="7:00")
#currently working but not what I want
new_df = orig.resample(rule="B", closed="right", label="left", base=23).sum()
#throws all kinds of erroes when trying to use my custom business hour
new_df = orig.resample(rule=bh, closed="right", label="left", base=23).sum()
```

I have been unable to implement my custom business day in the resample. With the above example it bins the investment column by day, ignoring the custom business day I am trying to implement

Comment: What is the error? *Values falls after last bin*? There are a bit of open, related requests to that error: [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15549), [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12351), [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12037). Theories are timezone or nano-/milli-second issue.

Comment: yes, that is the error, I also saw those open requests I will follow closely the newest release. Thank you for bringing it up.